# How to copy files across to a new folder in c# console application

Tags: c#, file, console-application

How do I copy across a file to another location in c# and overwrite the file if it exists.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        string sitemap_path = "T:\\somefolder\\somefolder\\somefolder\\Sitemap.xml";
        string server_path ="X:\\somefolder\\somefolder\\somefolder";
        File.Copy(sitemap_path,server_path,true);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I believe there is a `Directory` class in C#?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have so far? Does it not compile (if so what's the compiler error)? Does it fail with an exception (if so what is the exception and where is it thrown)? Does it fail silently? Does it copy the wrong file? Does it copy the right file to the wrong destination? We need more information before we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have forgotten to give the file name in new path:

```
File.Copy(sitemap_path,server_path + "\\newFileName.xml", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to include the file name in the server path string not just the destination directory 
See:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx